# При вызове MessageBox выводит вместо текста иероглифы

Tags: winapi, c++

Написал программу, выводящую Hello World в окошке MessageBox. Скомпилировал в MSVS 2008, а вывел какие-то то ли японские, то ли китайские иероглифы (буквально). В чем может быть проблема:

```
#include<windows.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                   int nCmdShow)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, 
               (LPCWSTR) "Hello, World!!!",
               (LPCWSTR) "Hello from MessageBox",
               MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Иногда бывают подобные проблемы при копировании текста.

Comment: Проблема в этом: `(LPCWSTR)`. Не нужно использовать явное C-like приведение типов. Этим Вы только затыкаете рот компилятору, который явственно обругался бы о том что, не может привести char [] к wchar_t*. Как правильно замечено - лучше используйте макрос _T и тип TCHAR для написания переносимых программ. Еще вариант - использование CString, который умеет преобразовываться куда надо (правда, нужно аккуратно обращаться со встроенным буфером).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Как и в одном из предущих ваших вопросов попробуйте использовать тип TCHAR:

```
#include <tchar.h>
```

и

```
MessageBox(
    NULL, 
    _T("Hello, World!!!"),
    _T("Hello from MessageBox"),
    MB_OK
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема с кодировкой. Попробуйте в свойствах проекта указать, что не нужно использовать unicode.

Comment: Во-первых, наоборот нужно, а во-вторых, там каст же, так что проблема не совсем с кодировкой.

Answer (score 0):

MS VS2010: Проект-->Свойства-->Свойства конфигурации-->Общие-->Набор символов= "Использовать набор символов Юникода":

```
MessageBox( NULL, 
            (LPCWSTR) TEXT("Hello, World!!!"), 
            (LPCWSTR) TEXT("Hello from MessageBox"), 
            MB_OK
           );
```

или

```
MessageBox( NULL, 
            TEXT("Hello, World!!!"), 
            TEXT("Hello from MessageBox"), 
            MB_OK
           );
```

Comment: Не поможет, там каст неверный.

Comment: У меня работает. Видимо автопреобразование.

Но второй вариант - без проблем

Comment: В варианте

MessageBox(NULL, 
               (LPCWSTR) "Hello, World!!!",
               (LPCWSTR) "Hello from MessageBox",
               MB_OK);

у меня тоже иероглифы в окне сообщения, при Юникоде. Но изменить Юникод на другое - не всегда возможно или непросто, но не для данного примера-вопроса, конечно

Comment: Причем для оригинала:
"Hello, World!!!" - как иероглифы, а
"Hello from MessageBox" - выводиться нормально после иероглифов.

И в заголовке окна - тоже ирероглифы, но другие ...

В ответе с _Т(,,,) сложнее - дополнительно нужно добавить #include <tchar.h>

Comment: Второй вариант - ok. А первый - нет, поскольку работает только в одном случае из двух.